# Maven how to exclude jar files in war but need it for the build

Tags: maven-3

I am new to maven.
I am using maven 3.6.2
I am using jdk 1.7.
Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I have a dependency in pom.xml:

```
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</catalina>
                <version>7.0.12</version>
            </dependency>
```

I need the above dependency to do a build:
dos-prompt>mvn clean install

But when use it in a tomcat 7 I need to exclude the above jar file in the war file that is the result of the build.

Comment: I think that's what `<scope>provided</scope>` is for

Comment: Thank you!!! You're right!!!